# Playa field not outputting expected value in zoo visitor update form

Tags: safecracker, playa, zoo-visitor

I'm trying to implement Chosen as a front to a Playa-field in my Zoo Visitor channel. Entering data isn't a problem, but obviously I want to have the currently selected entry selected as default. This wasn't behaving as expected, so I stripped everything down to the following bit of code:

```
{exp:zoo_visitor:update_form
    return='profiel'
    class='custom profile'
    allowed_groups='7'
}
    {member_employer var_prefix="employer"}{employer:entry_id}{/member_employer}
{/exp:zoo_visitor:update_form}
```

When I load this template, it outputs `810`, which isn't even an actual entry. When I output the value in another template between `{exp:zoo_visitor:details}` tags it outputs the expected entry_id of `243`. I've tried removing the var_prefix (which was only added later for debugging to be safe anyway). Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

The update form works just the same as a Channel Form. You are trying to use tag syntax that works inside a channel entries tag, but that won't work inside a form. Either use {field:your_playa_fieldname}  or if you really want to fetch them separately, you will have to resort to using a channel entries tag inside an embed.  Also have a look at this thread http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/zoo-visitor/viewthread/10501#37493

Cheers,
Nico

Comment: That's what I thought, shame though because it works for most "normal" fields. How would I go about getting the current entry_id into that embed? From what I can gather now this would require me to write 2 embeds: one for getting the current value and then pass the entry_id on to another embed for outputting the options.

Comment: the entry_id variable is directly available in the update form, so just pass that into the embed

Comment: Wait, but this entire question is about the entry_id not outputting correctly...